# Windows 10 high RAM usage

Tags: windows-10, memory, memory-leaks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF6PF.jpg

Hi,

I think I have a memory leak and I don't know what to do next after using Poolmon

I think that the first three tags on poolmon keep increasing in memory used so they're probably the cause of the memory leak.

From what I've read if there was a memory leak, the paged and non paged pool as shown on RamMap should be using way more RAM, but RamMap shows that the most RAM is used by Process Private, although the only programms that are running are those you can see on task manager.On task manager the process using most RAM is bitdefender with 300MB, so I'm feeling a bit lost.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF6PF.jpg

Comment: It looks like you are not using enough RAM: there is still 1.3GB available. You may be worrying about something that does not exist ;)

Comment: But after a reset my RAM usage drops at 35%.If my PC keeps running the RAM usage will even reach 99%, making my PC unusable, which sounds just like a memory leak

Answer (score 0):

ive got this problem too but after i downloaded Mem Reduct it really helped me

download it here: https://www.henrypp.org/product/memreduct
good cleaner and lightweight